# I need to run Command-Line Ioncube (PHP Encoder) with --release-license command option on OS X

Tags: php, macos, command-line, ioncube

To release license of my Ioncube (an OS X application), it says:

> To revoke your license, please run the command line Encoder with the --release-license option.
>
> Command line Encoders can be found in the /Applications/ionCube PHP Encoder.app/Contents/MacOS/ directory.

I tried doing this by running this in terminal:

`cd /Applications/ionCube\ PHP\ Encoder.app/Contents/MacOS`

`open -n ioncube_encoder5_9.0 --release-license`

Which fails: `open: unrecognized option '--release-license'`

I don't know anything about command line and I've been trying to do this `--release-license` for +2 hours now and tried many things, Googled/Searched a lot and still couldn't do it.
The whole program is GUI , I don't know why they force us to use command-line for this!

Comment: What is the result of the command when you run it in Terminal?

Comment: @l'L'l Added it to question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of running `open -n ioncube_encoder5_9.0 --release-license`, run the command:

```
./ioncube_encoder5_9.0 --release-license
```

(i.e., omitting the `open -n`). Please also verify that your Encoder is indeed licensed by restarting the Encoder.

You can also create a support ticket at the [ionCube HelpDesk](http://support.ioncube.com) for individual support.

Comment: I don't know how to thank you SebiH, It took me 2 hours and was really hopeless, this worked and returned `The license has been released successfully.`